# python Idle stopped working after Win10 update

Tags: python, updates

Win10 64 bit, Dell XPS13.
A couple of months ago I wrote and continued to run a simple Python program under IDLE 3.7. On 2nd October, this worked fine. On the night of the 2nd, Win10 update to version 1909 ran. (There is a message that the latest update 2004 failed to install in August.) Since then the first line, #!/usr/bin/env python3, gives an invalid syntax error. Microscoft chat help suggested I reinstall Python.  So I unistalled 3.7 and tried to install 3.8 from the Python website. This suggested I install the 32 bit, but I found the 64 bit version so downloaded and installed that. Still the same error. Uninstalled that, then installed the recommended 32 bit version.

When I click on my program with a .py extension, the program does not run. If I load IDLE, load the program and run it, I get the invalid syntax error. If I go to "Open with" and choose IDLE from the program folder, I get an error - this app will not run on this computer.

I guess that the Win10 update version 1909 has done something serious to the system, since it isn't reporting correctly to the Python website, nor is it able to run Python/IDLE.  So far, no other program appears to be failing, but it is early days yet.

Any ideas welcome.
Thank you

Comment: `#` signifies a comment. What is the *precise* error message? Do you have `env` installed? Is your Python interpreter really named `python3.exe`?

Comment: Error messages1. When I click on my program with a .py extension, the program does not run. If I load IDLE, load the program and run it, I get the invalid syntax error. If I go to "Open with" and choose IDLE from the program folder, I get an error - this app will not run on this computer.

Comment: It took me about 8 minutes to write the comment, so it seems to have been lost with the 5 minute time limit.  What should I do next?

Comment: env installed: I don't know. But in installing python, I clicked adding it to the path, and C:Program Files (x86)\Python39-32 is in the Path statement, so assume is  Error messages1. When I click on my program with a .py extension, I now get   "This app can't run on your PC ¦To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.". 2. If I load IDLE, load the program and run it, I get "SyntaxError ¦invalid syntax" 3. If I go to "Open with" and choose IDLE from the program folder, I get  "This app can't run on your PC ¦To find a version for your PC,check with the software publisher."